# Python how to insert data from dataframe to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I get row of datafram and insert to mysql with this code, res is data I want to insert to mysql.

```
res = df.loc[df.ID == l_id]
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO log (id, user, number, state, j_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )"
val = [(None, res['User'], res['Pages'] , res['State'], l_id )]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.") 

mycursor.close()
```

when I run it show error like this.

```
ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'series' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

How to add data from dataframe to MySQL?

Comment: what is the type of res['User']? you probably need to convert it to string/int/similar types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val = [(None, res['User'].item(), res['Pages'].item() , res['State'].item(), l_id )]
```

The res['User'] by itself returns a pandas object which you can't pass as mysql arguments. You need to extract the value of the pandas object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_dict()`. JFYI: [item() deprecated 0.25.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/base.py#L724-L740).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': ('first', 'sec',),
    'ID': (1, 2,),
    'Pages': (1, 2,),
    'State': ('active', 'not active',),
})


l_id = 1
users = df.loc[df.ID == l_id].to_dict('records')
print(users)  # [{'User': 'first', 'ID': 1, 'Pages': 1, 'State': 'active'}]

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO log (id, user, number, state, j_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )"
# insert first user from list
val = (None, users[0]['User'], users[0]['Pages'], users[0]['State'], l_id)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `to_records` with `executemany`. The resulting numpy record arrays append may migrate like list of tuples into SQL.

Also, instead of appending `None` to render as `NULL`, simply leave out the column in append query. And why not use the data frame's `ID` which would be same as the variable `l_id`? And in case your data frame contains other unneeded columns for table insert, use `reindex` to subset columns.

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# FILTER ROWS AND COLUMNS
res = df[df.ID == l_id].reindex(['User', 'Pages', 'State', 'ID'], axis=1)

sql = "INSERT INTO log (user, number, state, j_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"

mycursor.executemany(sql, res.to_records(index=False))         
myconn.commit()
```

Alternatively, import via list of tuples:

```
mycursor.executemany(sql, res.apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist())   
myconn.commit()
```